# accessing cloud storage directly from an android application

Tags: android, database, google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I am creating an android application which needs to have a cloud database. I want to use google cloud storage which can act as a database for me. But I do not want to create a backend (Server Side) to retrieve my information. Instead I want to directly retrieve the information on the mobile client.

Is it possible? How can I achieve such a mechanism and what do we call it? Are there any links/tutorials to follow? The one so far I was able to find was the one in which I have to use app engine for my back end.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean Google Cloud Storage or AppEngine datastore?

Comment: Whats the difference ? :(

Comment: Google Cloud Storage is their blob and object store (i.e. to store files). AppEngine datastore is a NoSql database but you need to run an app within appengine to access it. Then there's Google Cloud Datastore which is a NoSql DB-as-a-service.

Comment: If its Google Cloud datastore. Can I access it directly from an android application? Or do I have to write a separate WebService in order to access it?

Comment: it's in beta, so not sure I would trust it for a production app. If you want a service-less DB access, I recommend looking at MongoLab.

Comment: Im looking for a database cloud service where I can access DB directly from an app without getting into the trouble of creating my own webservice to access the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can purchase only database service with either Amazon Web Services or Windows Azure.

---

A link with explanations about the different DB services can be found here:

http://aws.amazon.com/running_databases/

Instructions on how to use amazon database can be found here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html#Welcome.Interfaces

---

Also, Windows Azure have a database service. Explanations can be found here:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/sql-database/

Instructions on how to use Azure database can be found here:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/sql-database/

---

Both database and cloud providers allow you to access the database directly using REST.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Google Cloud save](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/cloudsave) or [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui).

Cloud save is useful for game apps to save  small amount of data such as the current score of each user, level progress in a game and so on.

Google Drive SDK is designed to meet a large range of developer needs like sharing files with other users, managing a set of multiple files and subdirectories, add and reply to comments and so on.

Comment: Thank you. But I have to store huge amount of data. So I need to use a Cloud Service.